# Dropping many values

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Two questions for one

1) With `Drop` I can drop 1 to many elements as soon as they are connected. But suppose that I want to eliminate all the 0 in `{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 23, 0}` without knowing where they are. Of Course I can do this with

```
 Cases[Complement[{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 23, 0}, Cases[{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 23, 0}, 0]]]
```

which gives

> {1, 2, 3, 5, 23}

But I have also a second set, `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}`, and I need to drop the letters which are in the same positions as the zeros in the first set, so using

```
Position[{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 23, 0}, 0]
```

I can find the position of the zeros which is given as a list so I can remove the first 0 with

```
Drop[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, {Position[{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 23, 0},0][[1,1]]}]
```

and so on for the others. But I don't know how to pass many 0 positions when they are not linked.

Comment: `Delete[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, 
 Position[{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 23, 0}, 0]]`?

Comment: Thanks both  The lists must have the same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Delete[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, Position[{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 23, 0}, 0]]
```

> {b, c, e, f, h}

Or

```
ReplacePart[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i},
  Position[{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 23, 0}, 0] -> Sequence[]]
```

> {b, c, e, f, h}

If you have to use `Drop`:

```
Fold[Drop, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, Reverse@Position[{0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 23, 0}, 0]]
```

> {b, c, e, f, h}

Answer (score 4):

```
list1 = {0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 23, 0};
list2 = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
Pick[list2, DiracDelta@list1, 0]
```

> {b, c, e, f, h}

Use `DiracDelta[# - x0] &` to pick elements in `list2` corresponding to where `x0` in `list1` are.

Comment: Why not just `Pick[list2, list1, x_ /; x != 0]`?

Comment: @Alan: why not with `DiracDelta`, to ask a rhetorical question too. Things can be done differently in MMA, and I found this one the most interesting for me. You can of course make a separate answer with your own idea...

Comment: The "why not" is computational cost: first you must compute the DiracDelta, then you must compare to `0`.

Comment: ... and provide a timing comparison ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
list1 = {0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 23, 0};
list2 = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
Pick[list2, list1, x_ /; x != 0]
```